# Amazon SES for incoming mail. What are the advantages?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, smtp, email-server, amazon-ses

I am just in the process of setting up Amazon SES on my domain for outgoing mail so any email sent from my domain or website is sent through Amazon.

Now there's a question it asks, "Would you like to setup Amazon SES also to receive mail?

Huh, I don't know. Should I? I'm already using Amazon AWS and S3, so I guess it wouldn't be a hassle setting it up, but are there any advantages of receiving email through Amazon?

I am currently receiving mail through my own domain's server and I get about 20 emails per day tops.

Are there any advantages of receiving email through Amazon SES instead ??

Comment: It can be used to programmatically handle incoming mail. If you already have incoming mail handled, a) having SES handle it would break your current mail setup and b) be a bunch of unnecessary work.

Comment: I wouldn't be setting up Amazon SES to receive email additionally to my current incoming server. I'm asking if I should replace this completely and go with Amazon SES instead of my current incoming server and if there are any advantages to do so at all?

Comment: Advantages other than storing received emails in Amazon S3 rather than my own server ..

Comment: It'd let you have certain emails delivered to things like SNS. That said, SES doesn't provide mailboxes like a traditional mail provider/system would.